# How to print dates from csv file in python without importing pandas

Tags: python, csv

i have data in csv file data as follow
2021-03-26
2021-03-27
2021-04-03

I want the output as {2021-03-26,2021-03-27,2021-04-03}

Answer (score 0):

you can read the file and its data and split it with space.

if your csv contains data on multiple lines then you can add for loop for each line and split each line you will get the list of dates.

check below code:

```
with open("csv file path", 'r') as fp:
    data = fp.read()
    
data = data.strip()
dates = data.split(' ')
print(dates)
```